# Does windows 7 have a 'force-quit' shortcut key combination?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

Sometimes applications like to override the close button on the window pane, so <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and the like don't work.

I want to know if there is a quick way to hard shut-down the active application without having to open up the Task Manager, find the active process, and then end it.

Comment: Which app overrides Alt-F4?

Comment: Many programs allow CTRL W for close (Firefox does ALT + F + X), but can you explain what programs do this as Poldie asked?

Comment: @Poldie Many games actually catch you hitting **Alt+F4** (they "handle" the keypress or the actual window message) so it's never passed back to system (to be handled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not have a `force-quit` shortcut key combination. But many programs respond to different key combinations regardless, such as ALT-F4, CTRL-W, or a custom combination specifically for that program.

Alternatively, if it is just one program you want to be able to force-quit by the press of a button (because ALT-F4 does not work) you can use the commandline taskkill /f to force close an application. By creating a shortcut (and optionally assign it a shortcut key) you can close the program by either launching your shortcut or by pressing the shortcut key.

Lets assume the program you want to close is Internet Explorer. Your shortcut would be this:

[image]

The application is: `C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /f /fi "imagename eq Iexplore*"`

Comment: Thanks. I used this technique in combination with http://www.autohotkey.com/ and getting the active process id.

Answer (score 0):

In short;

No

Other examples look like too much work. You have to create a shortcut for each program manually. Maybe there's an app that.